# ajaxtoolkit progress update javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, modalpopupextender

I am using ajaxtoolkit modalpopupextender to display a processing message. It's working fine on a typical postback (button click, etc).

However, I am calling a postback in javascript and the progress message isn't showing UNLESS I add an "alert" in the javascript.

Here's my javascript:

```
function getOrder() {
    beginRequest('', '')
    var hid = document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_hid");
    //alert(hid.value);

    __doPostBack("SaveOrder", hid.value);
    endRequest('', '')
}
```

I obviously don't want to have an "alert" so does anyone have a solution or ran into this?

Here's the other pience of javascript used relating to this (typical stuff):

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(beginRequest);
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(endRequest);    

var mdlCtl = document.getElementById('ctl00_hfModalCtlID').value;

function beginRequest(sender, args){
    $find(mdlCtl).show();
}

function endRequest(sender, args) {
    $find(mdlCtl).hide();
}
```

I'm stumped on why the "alert" makes a difference in the javascript that shows the processing message...?

Thoughts? Ideas?

Comment: am still searching for an answer to this one. anyone?

Comment: anyone have any ideas?